# error while attempting to change aux directory

Tags: miktex, auxiliary-files, cleanup, directory

I used following command to change the directory of the aux and output directory

```
Specifying the Directory for Auxiliary Files

The option `--aux-directory=dir` causes TeX to create auxiliary files in another directory. For example:

> mkdir C:\texoutput
> mkdir C:\tobedeleted
> latex -output-directory=C:\texoutput -aux-directory=C:\tobedeleted foo.tex
...
> 
This ensures that 1) foo.dvi will be created in C:\texoutput\ and 2) all other files (foo.log, …) will be created in C:\tobedeleted\..
```

But by doing so, I have got myself into trouble. I am now getting following error

```
xelatex.exe: Windows API error 87: The parameter is incorrect. xelatex.exe: Data: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex/data/le\df2c24cb21984fa85003c1ecc818ff83.fndb

Process exited with error(s)
```

How can fix the problem or restore the default behaviour?

Comment: everybody who changes the directory for the output files has similar problems, it's always possible to fix them in the end, but it is far far simpler just not to do it:-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If MiKTeX is open, this error results. Just close all instances of MiKTeX and re-compile. 
Solved.